# Trouble implementing Key authentication in geoserver

Tags: geoserver, security, authentication

I'm trying to implement key authentication in geoserver 2.3.3. 
The steps I followed are:

- Added the authkey plugin
- Created the authkey filter
- Secured the layers by assigning workspaces to different users
- Added authkey filter to the filter chain

I'm passing the **authkey**(obtained from authkey.properties file) as a **parameter** along with the request while accessing the layers from the client side of my application. But still the authentication does'nt work and the layer's are inaccessible.
 Is there anything that I'm missing out or anything wrong with my procedure.
Kindly help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the answer myself.
The issue was with default filter chain. It was solved when I removed both basic and anonymous authentication from the chain and kept authkey authentication alone. Now I'm able to login from the client with the authkey of the respective user.

Comment: It should be sufficient just to add "authkey" on top of the default filters chain; using the web interface did not worked on GeoServer 2.17.0 for me, so I changed "security/config.xml" manually and restarted GeoServer.

Answer (score 2):

From our end (Geoserver 2.9.1 / 02d742eb7992fd70bc277cb873d7fbb2326a2eb0), we need to add our authkey authentication filter in the filter chain named "rest". If our authentication key filter was not placed in there (rest filter chain), it was not working properly. We also add to change the password encryption to Digest.